# How to remove macFUSE item from Finder menu?

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem

I have removed macFUSE but this item in the Finder menu still shows

```
pkgutil --pkgs |grep fuse
```

not found any Fuse packages

[image]

Comment: Isn't that just a list of recently-opened windows? What happens when you click on that one, and randomly one of the others you know for sure still exists? [If it *does* open a macFUSE window, check whether it's actually in the Trash. If so, empty Trash & look again.]

Comment: When I click it shows a popup "macFUSE folder can`t be found".
Trash is empty too.

Comment: So, I have installed the last version of macFUSE again and after installation, this menu item has been removed, then I removed macFUSE again too.